# Create dropdown banner when user first visits website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzMVz.jpg

When a user visits my webpage for the first time, I want the black banner to drop down and ask them a question or alert them. I don't know what this is called. If someone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. I'm sure there is a JS plug-in somewhere, but I can't find it.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to a plugin to do this.

In order to do this as cross-browser friendly as possible then use a cookie to know whether the user has visited before or not.

The code is pretty shabby but I hope it helps.

Initially if you hide the element with CSS you will not get a pop as javascript loads.

if you have the element at the top of your page so in your html document:

Add css:

```
<style>
.dropdown-notification {
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   position: relative;
   top: -40px;
   transition: top .2s; // don't forget to use prefixes
}
.dropdown-notification.active {
   top: 0;
}
</style>
```

Add to your body:

```
<body>

   <div class="dropdown-notification text-center">
      Hi, I'm a drop down <button class="close">Close</button>
   </div>

   ... rest of html here

</body>
```

And add this jQuery wrapped within document load, using cookie plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie:

```
// Check if cookie 
if ($.cookie("noti") !== "closed") { // or you could just check for cookie existing
   $('.dropdown-notification').addClass('active');
}

// On button click close and add cookie (expires in 100 days)
$('.close').on('click', function(){
   $.cookie("noti", "closed", { expires : 100 });
   $('.dropdown-notification').removeClass('active');
})
```

A [jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/SSh9M/1/)

Comment: +1 for concise code and the jsfiddle. That helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this and add a cookie to check if the user has visited the website before :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // check cookie
    var visited = $.cookie("visited")

    if (visited == null) {
        $('some-header').show();
        $.cookie('visited', 'yes'); 
        alert($.cookie("visited"));         
    }

    // set cookie
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
});
```

If you would like to go the pure Javascript route you can take a look at this webpage which uses these functions :
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use HTML5 local storage.

Here's the link:
[Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Simply check a variable like "visited"when they hit your page. If it's null, then set it to 1 or whatever and drop banner. Otherwise, do nothing.